# JWT RS256: Is it safe to fetch public key over https?

Tags: security, https, rsa, jwt, public-key

I'm signing JWT's using the RS256 algorithm. To verify those tokens on the client, I somehow need to access the public key.

Are there security concerns (spoofing, ...) when I set up an unprotected API route ('/api/certificate') that returns the certificate containing the public key. And do I need to take any extra security measurements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several concepts are often mixed up, maybe not for you, but let me try to explain a few things in this answer.

Assymetric cryptography obviously needs a public and a private key, both are basically just numbers. The private key is kept secret, the public is, well, public, anybody can have it. When signing stuff, you use the private key to sign and then anybody can verify using the public key that the signature was made by somebody that had the corresponding private key (ie. you).

But the question is then how you distribute your public key, or in your jwt example, how clients get it. As you correctly pointed out in the question, simply downloading the public key over an insecure channel is not good enough as an attacker could replace it with his own, resulting in the attacker being able to sign tokens.

One solution to this could be getting it over https as you proposed, which practically means using a second set of public-private keypair (keys of the webserver) to secure sending the first one. The theoretical question is still the same btw, it's just inherently solved in the background for you: how does the browser know that the public key it receives from the server upon connection actually belongs to the server. There is no secure channel yet between them.

Enter certificates.

**A certificate is a document that essentially ties a public key to its owner, and that is excactly what you want.** When a browser connects to a website, the server sends its public key *along with its certificate*, so that the browser can verify that the public key actually belongs to the server (the domain name in this case) that sent it. How that verifies it is beyond the scope of this post, the point is that the certificate is signed by another public key, the certificate to which may be signed by another public key, etc., and the chain is terminated by a list of so called trusted root certificates already set up for your computer and/or browser by your OS/browser vendor.

**And you too should verify the public key with the certificate the same way.** You don't even need the burden of SSL (https) transport for this, verifying that a public key belongs to a particular subject is the main purpose of certificates.

So all you have to do is not just get the public key from the API, but get it along with its certificate. You are probably already doing this, bare public keys are very rarely used. You are most probably already receiving a pfx or cer or crt or whatever from the server. Depending on the technology stack that you are developing on, you can for sure use built in mechanisms to fully verify a certificate and make sure it's valid. Please don't implement your own validation though, as that's tricky business and quite hard to get right. If the certificate passes validation, you can trust that the public key you received from the API is authentic and belongs to whatever it claims to belong to. There may be caveats though (like for example make sure that beyond basic validation, you check a combination of fields from the certificate that others can't have).

As an additional security measure, you can also implement *certificate pinning* to make it even more secure against certain types of attacks by having a list of fingerprints for valid certificates in the client (less so in a browser client, but still the concept is the same).

**Edit** (what fields to check in the certificate after it passed general validation of expiry, etc):

In the general case it depends on who signed the certificate and what kind of certificate it is.

A server certificate signed by a real certificate authority (CA) can only have the server domain as its common name (CN) field, a real CA won't normally sign anything else, and they also won't sign a certificate for yourdomain.com unless you can prove you control yourdomain.com. So in this case it may be enough to check CN after the cert passed validation. You do need to check CN though, as anybody can have a valid certificate from say GlobalSign or Thawte or other trusted CAs, it just costs money. What they can't have is a certificate for yourdomain.com.

If you sign your own certificates, you also won't sign anything for anyone, so in that case it could be enough to check the issuer (that you signed it) and the CN (for whom). If the certificate otherwise passed validation (meaning a trusted root certificate signed it) it should be ok, as an attacker won't normally be able to have his CA certificate as trusted on your computer.

The point in general is that you want to check something that others can't have. It's easier, if you are relying on real CAs, and it's usually best to check the fingerprint.

Comment: Your answer has been very interesting to read. I'll try to add certificate validation on top of using https. As you said I better don't implement my own validation, is parsing the certificate and checking the whole name string a good idea?

Comment: I added my thoughts to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comprehensive answer. I'll accept it!

Comment: Well, I think this doesn't answer the question. A client (browser or app) generates the JWT and sign it using its own public key. This key cannot be associated to a certificate, because it is the key of a client we are talking about. You do not certificate a client, but a server, a domain name. So if you generate a token client side, you still need to send the public key over HTTPS to a server with a valid certificate.

Comment: @noun I'm not following sorry. Why would a client generate a jwt? Why would it sign it with its *public* key? And even if it did for whatever reason, why could a server not validate a client certificate?

Comment: @GaborLengyel If you want to use the `jti` claim to avoid a replay attack the token must be generated client side and verified by the server. The client would sign the token with its **private key** (not the public, sorry for the mistake) so the server can verify the signature using the public key provided by the client over https in a previous call.

Comment: **simply downloading the public key over an insecure channel is not good enough as an attacker could replace it with his own, resulting in the attacker being able to sign tokens** _I dont get this. It's a public key how can attacker use it to sign tokens. Don't you need the private keys to sign tokens?_

Comment: @BilalFazlani Signing is not the problem, sorry if it was confusing - of course you need the private key to sign. However, that signature must then be verified, and the public key is used for verification. The question is then which public key? If the attacker can replace the public key used for verification, he can then sign with the corresponding private key that he has. So in other words, it's not the attacker knowing the publickey that's the problem, but changing it. A public key is not a secret, but it's integrity and authenticity needs to be protected. The standard way is a certificate.

Comment: Aaaaaa that makes sense. Thanks @Gabor